# Show that if $O$ is an open in $(M, d)$, then $O$ is open in $(M, d_{A})$.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I want to prove that if $O$ is an open in $(M, d)$, then $O$ is open in $(M, d_{A})$, where $$d_{A}(x, y)=\min\left\lbrace\ d(x, y), 1\right\rbrace$$ where $d(x, y)$ is a metric.

My attempt was based on the following. Since $O$ is an open in $(M, d)$, given $x \in O$, there exists $r>0$ such that $$B(x; r) \subseteq O$$
It would then suffice to prove that for some $r_{1}>0$ $$B_{d_{A}}(x; r_{1})\subseteq B(x; r) \subseteq O$$

Let $y \in B_{d_{A}}(x; r_{1})$ then $\min\left\lbrace\ d(x, y), 1\right\rbrace < r_{1}$, take $r_{1}=1$ and $d(x, y)<r_{1}$ now, my question is should I take $r_{1}=r=1$ ? or how can I conclude? any suggestion is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take $r_1 = \text{min}\{r, 1\} $, for in this case, if $y \in B_{d_A} (x, r_1)$, then $\min\{ d(x,y), 1\} < r_1 \leq 1$, so $ d(x,y) < r_1 \leq r$.